# CSS circle rainbow color rotation

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I would like to be able to create a circle multicolor like this image
http://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/android-app-inventor/114178d1398172852t-game-free-true-color-icon_256.png

And make it rotate infinite..
I need it for Ionic app, If anyone know this app have example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aurelhubert.truecolor&hl=it

Comment: Can you use the image or you want that in full CSS ?

Comment: Yes maybe I can use image and rotate it, is more simple... But how can I did some like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEVjLfq9lvk ( I would like to make the "play" effect and the color spin effect and fire event when it load 100%)..

Comment: You probably need more than just some CSS. For complexes animations use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple using CSS keyframe animations combined with rotation transformations:

```css
div {
  background: url(http://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/android-app-inventor/114178d1398172852t-game-free-true-color-icon_256.png) no-repeat;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  -webkit-animation: rot 4s linear 0s infinite;
     -moz-animation: rot 4s linear 0s infinite;
       -o-animation: rot 4s linear 0s infinite;
          animation: rot 4s linear 0s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rot { from { transform: rotate(0deg) } to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
   @-moz-keyframes rot { from { transform: rotate(0deg) } to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
     @-o-keyframes rot { from { transform: rotate(0deg) } to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
        @keyframes rot { from { transform: rotate(0deg) } to { transform: rotate(360deg) }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Of course, you can achieve more fancy effects by specifying more rules in keyframes, but this should be enough to get you started.

Useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: Thanks! I will try out it this weekend :D